# Parsing String into tokens in C - what's going wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, argv, strsep

I'm trying to split a string into tokens to create an array of argument parameters. My current implementation is as follows (`path` is the path to the user-executable file for which optional arguments are being read):

```
// ARG_MAX as defined in limits.h
int execute(char *exe) {
    printf("args to %s: ", exe);

    char *args = malloc(ARG_MAX);
    scanf("%s", args);

    char *argv[ARG_MAX];

    int i = 0;
    argv[i++] = exe;

    while ((argv[i] = strsep(&args, " \t")) != NULL) {
        i++;
    }

    free(args);
    execv(exe, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

What's confusing me is that from my understanding of `strsep` this should be working as intended, and it does to an extent in that when tested it accurately allocates `tokens[0]` to be `path`, and `tokens[1]` to be whatever `tokens_s` up to the first whitespace character is.

When after a space you enter another argument, however, this is not allocated into `tokens[2]`, and so on for subsequent arguments.

I can't seem to spot what it is I've done wrong when using `strsep` that isn't leading to the desired functionality?

input:
`exe = "/usr/bin/ps"`
`args = "-e -l"`

output:
`exec ps -e`

Comment: `scanf("%s", args);` does not save `'\t'` nor spaces into `args`.  Use `fgets()`.  Suggest posting your input used.

Comment: have added input. have tried using `fgets()` but at the point where I should be prompted to enter the arguments at the command line, it just continues without prompting?

Comment: As this post lacks a complete compilable code, it just makes it harder than needed to help.  Adding `fgets()` likely is a problem because other code is still using `scanf()`.  Strongly recommend to post a complete minimal code that shows the problem.

Comment: Sorry, there is not much extra context to the code, I've updated to include the full method. There's no other code running using scanf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple errors:

- You must read the arguments with `fgets()` to read multiple words.
- You must use a temporary variable for `strsep()` so you can pass the original pointer from `malloc()` back to `free()`, or simply use a local array.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

// ARG_MAX as defined in limits.h
int execute(char *exe) {
    char args[ARG_MAX + 1];

    printf("args to %s: ", exe);
    fflush(stdout);
    if (fgets(args, sizeof args, stdin)) {
        char *argv[ARG_MAX / 2];
        char *p;

        int i = 0;
        argv[i++] = exe;

        p = args;
        args[strcspn(args, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline if present
        while ((argv[i] = strsep(&p, " \t")) != NULL) {
            i++;
        }

        printf("argv: ");
        for (i = 0; argv[i]; i++)
            printf(" '%s'", argv[i]);
        printf("\n");

        execv(exe, argv);
        printf("exec failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    } else {
        printf("cannot read input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *exe = "printf";
    if (argc > 1)
        exe = argv[1];
    return execute(exe);
}
```

Notes:

- `execv` will not return to your program if it succeeds.
- `strsep` does not collapse sequences of separators, your method will create extra arguments if you have extra spaces.

**EDIT:** If input is read from `stdin` before you get to run `execute`, and if such input is performed with calls to `scanf()`, there might be a pending newline in the `stdin` buffer, and `fgets()` would read it as an empty line. If this is the case, first flush the pending input before calling `printf()`:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is helpful as to how it should be correctly implemented, however `"args to %s", exe` never gets printed to console and instead program executes with no arguments with this code?

This is the problem I keep having trying to use `fgets()` and `getline()`.

In my original code above it would still print the prompt and execute but only recognise the first argument

Comment: @transiti0nary: if you add the `fflush(stdout);`, does the prompt get printed?  Are you sure you can read from standard input? I updated my answer to make failure more explicit.

Comment: Yeah the prompt now prints, but it still does not halt for input and just runs the exec with no arguments

Comment: There must be something wrong in your environment.  Can you describe how you are compiling and executing the above program?  I added a simple `main` function for testing and it works fine on OS/X

Comment: The function is part of a larger library of functions for extracting data and performing actions on a given filepath, it would probably be simpler to try and work out what could be the cause of this sort of problem than to rake through all the other functions on here to see where the exact issue lies, I am compiling on OSX using `gcc -o fileinfo ~/fileinfolib.c ~/fileinfo.c`. `fileinfo.c` contains only a main method, which calls a library function to present file info to the user, then prompting them what to do depending on file type. If it is an exe, this method is called

Comment: `gcc` is actually a wrapper on `clang` on OS/X. I suggest compiling with `-Wall -O2` or `-Weverything -O2` to get useful warnings about potential programming errors. Production code should compile without any warnings with this extra level enabled.

Comment: If the`execute()`  function does prompt for arguments but does not read them, it is possible that `stdin` be closed redirected from a file and at the end of the file, but you should get the error message if `fgets()` returns `NULL`. There is another possibility as explained in my updated answer.

Comment: It seems there was something pending in the buffer as your updated answer addresses the issue. The method now works as expected, thank you! Is there any reason this while loop is fixing the problem where `fflush()` or `clearerr()` were not?

Comment: @transiti0nary: `clearerr()` just clears the error condition if there was a read error, you are not likely to encounter read errors nowadays, bad sectors are quite rare now. `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior. On some environments it might clear the input buffer, but you cannot rely on this.  Use the loop in my answer instead.